# How to filter out all .cs files inside a solution (.sln) file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, roslyn, solution

I am currently working on a project where i want to analyse someones code and then make a class diagram out of it. I am making this website with the .NET MVC Framework.

What i have so far is a form where the user can upload their .sln file. Now i have to figure out how to seperate the .cs files from the solution to analyse the classes and convert them to XML. I am still a beginner when it comes to C# and this framework in general. I would really appreciate if someone can give me some tips on how to do this in the most efficient way possible. I have read some things about Roslyn but im not sure if there are more efficient ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Solution files don't list C# files at all. They just say what the projects are. Old-style projects usually *did* list the C# files in those projects, but new "SDK-style" projects usually don't (fortunately). Basically if the user *only* uploads their solution file, that's hardly going to give you any information.

Comment: A .sln file doesn't directly reference .cs files, only project files (ah bugg'a, sniped by Skeet)

Comment: @JonSkeet I didnt know that, thank you!  What if i let them upload their project folder? what would be the best way to filter out all the .cs files by going thru the project folder?

Comment: Uploading an entire folder may be tricky to code over a web UI - and for a whole *solution* there could be multiple projects. You wouldn't want to upload the built binaries, probably - or maybe you should *just* ask users to upload the DLL/EXE files, and then just analyze those...